# java.lang.NullPointerException Google Maps Android API V2

Tags: android, api, nullpointerexception, maps

I would like to begin by saying I know this error has been posted about 2,000 times, but after looking through pages and pages of people with the same issue and trying all of their fixes, none of them have worked so I decided to make a new question. I apologize if there is a thread with a solution for my specific problem, I was not able to locate it.

With that out of the way, I believe the error is that there is a NullPointerException on line 41 of MainActivity.Java, because the Google Map is null and not being initialized.

Line 41 is as follows:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapU)).getMap();
```

If I remove all of my code from MainActivity.Java, leaving only the code generated by Android Studio, the app starts up fine and will display a Google Map of the World, so I don't think it has anything to do with my API key or Google Play Services not being updated.

Some stuff I have tried is:

-Switching from FragmentManager to SupportFragmentManager on line 41 (When I did this I changed the map from FragmentMap to SupportMapFragment)
-Adding permissions to the Manifest file, you can see everything I have ended up with.
-Different devices (Doesn't work on a Samsung Galaxy S2 or a Galaxy S4)
-I was originally on minSDK 12, decided to change to 16 just to see if it would help, nothing

NOTE: When I first created this project, for some reason the MainActivity.Java said extends ActionBarActivity instead of FragmentActivity, so I changed it to say FragmentActivity, but I was having this issue both before and after.

Manifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hasan.maps" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.hasan.maps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="APIKEY_IS_INSERTED_HERE"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.hasan.maps;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap map;
private final LatLng Location_NJIT = new LatLng(40.7406517, -74.1792757);
private final LatLng Location_Stevens = new LatLng(40.7469309, -74.0258336);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();

                 }
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapU)).getMap();


}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onClick_city (View v){

}
public void onClick_njit (View v){
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Location_NJIT);
    map.animateCamera(update);
}
public void onClick_stevens (View v){

}


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Logcat

```
Logcat

01-31 00:08:42.050  14353-14353/com.hasan.maps E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hasan.maps/com.hasan.maps.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)


 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.hasan.maps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4938)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

Fragment_Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.hasan.maps.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">



    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/mapU"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/stevens" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="City"
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:layout_above="@+id/map"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/header"
        android:onClick="onClick_city" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NJIT"
        android:id="@+id/njit"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/city"
        android:onClick="onClick_njit" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stevens"
        android:id="@+id/stevens"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/njit"
        android:onClick="onClick_stevens" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is on MainActivity.java line number 41 ?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapU)).getMap();

Answer (score 1):

//Actually you have declared **frafment** id `android:id="@+id/mapU"`  in layout `Fragment_Main.xml`

but your are calling in `MainActivity.java` with layout `activity_main.xml`

make sure that you are declared map fragment in `activity_mail.xml.`

or call the map in your

```
PlaceholderFragment

 map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()rootView.findFragmentById(R.id.mapU)).getMap();
```

Comment: In the Fragment_Main.xml I named it mapU because I thought there might have been a problem with naming my variable map and also naming the fragment map.

Comment: no its fragment  i am able to show Map when i cut the give Code but when i try to display multiple location then this Error Coming

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

I figured it out finally after hours of tearing my hair out. The code had to be moved under the Fragment Activity Class.